# Extraction of data (specific word) from a text file using Matlab

Tags: matlab, extract

I am trying to get some specific information from a text file, but my code isn't bringing out the result I needed. Example of a file I have is:

```
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'I|PSnd:  61|snd[3D]:FFFF m:0x6564 e:0'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'I|PSnd: 233|sD[3D]m:0x6564 e:0'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'D|Beat:1234|WDTimeout: 300'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'D|Beat:1256|sd:0x6564: e:0'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'D|Beat:1276|sprts'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'D|Beat:5460|GetPckt:0x3901'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'D|Beat:7085|Prtns->'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'D|Beat:1975|sevt:72'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'D|Beat:1780|snd:0x3901'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'I|PSnd:  61|snd[B0]:FFFF m:0x3901 e:0'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'I|PSnd: 233|sD[B0]m:0x3901 e:0'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'D|Beat:1833|sd:0x3901:0'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'D|Beat:1200|Rcv<-RP, s:1402'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'D|Beat:1220|FrMsg:0x467b QMsg:0x5840'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'I|Beat:13031|n:1402 rssi:-91, lqi:255, q:61'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'D|Beat:8868|sameRP'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'D|Beat:5460|GetPckt:0x41a1'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'D|Beat:1975|sevt:40'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.22Z 'D|Beat:13282|PR->:1402 LRPID:C1402'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.22Z 'D|Beat:1780|snd:0x41a1'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.22Z 'D|Beat:1791|evtT:3498847'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.22Z 'I|PSnd:  61|snd[3D]:1402 m:0x41a1 e:0'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.22Z 'I|PSnd: 233|sD[3D]m:0x41a1 e:0'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.22Z 'D|Beat:1234|WDTimeout: 300'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.22Z 'D|Beat:1256|sd:0x41a1: e:0'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.22Z 'D|Beat:1200|Rcv<-RP, s:1202'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.22Z 'D|Beat:1220|FrMsg:0x502a QMsg:0x3eef'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.22Z 'I|Beat:13031|n:1202 rssi:-94, lqi:255, q:60'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.22Z 'D|Beat:8868|sameRP'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.22Z 'D|Beat:5460|GetPckt:0x51c8'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.22Z 'D|Beat:1975|sevt:40'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.22Z 'D|Beat:13282|PR->:1202 LRPID:61202'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.22Z 'D|Beat:1780|snd:0x51c8'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.22Z 'D|Beat:1791|evtT:3498847'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.22Z 'I|PSnd:  61|snd[3D]:1202 m:0x51c8 e:0'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.24Z 'I|PSnd: 233|sD[3D]m:0x51c8 e:0'
```

in the file above, I am trying to extract every line that contains 'sD' but the previous line must contain 'snd'. I am trying to get both date and the value [3D] out in some output column and maybe all the extracted lines in a different array.

What I have done:
I tried using the Psnd as the query line, This can be seen in the script below

```
queryline = 'PSnd';
fID = fopen('log1.txt');
C = textscan(fID,'%s','delimiter','\n');
fclose(fID);
C = C{1};
[temp,matchedLines] = regexp(C,['(?<date>^[0-9,-:T]*)Z.*' queryline ':(?<Num>[0-9A-Z|A-Z[0-9A-Z:]]*)'] ,'tokens','match');
matchedLines = [matchedLines{:}]';
temp = [temp{:}];
temp = reshape([temp{:}],2,[])';
outTime  = datetime(temp(:,1),'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSS');
[h,m,s]= hms(outTime);
time = {h; m; s};
time_in_hrs = [time{:}];
t = [time{1:3}];

nodes_in_clus = temp(:,2);
```

and I am getting some very weird result, am soo not understanding. My initial error was

```
Error using datetime (line 556)
Numeric input data must be a matrix with three or six columns, or else three or six separate numeric arrays. You can also create datetimes from a single numeric array using the
'ConvertFrom' parameter.

Error in get_cluster (line 10)
outTime2= datetime(temp2(:,1), 'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSS');
```

but after  making some changes I got a this as my result

```
'2017-10-02T23:58:26.62Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:26.77Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:26.77Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:26.91Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:26.91Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:27.06Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:27.06Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:27.20Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:27.20Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:27.35Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:27.35Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:27.49Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:27.49Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:27.64Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:27.64Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:27.79Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:27.79Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:27.93Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:27.93Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:28.06Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:28.06Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:28.21Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:28.21Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:28.36Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:28.36Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:28.51Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:28.51Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:28.65Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:28.65Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:28.79Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:28.79Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:28.94Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:28.94Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:40.39Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:40.39Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:40.39Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:40.39Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:51.76Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:51.76Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:51.76Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:51.87Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:51.87Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:51.92Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:51.92Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:52.02Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:52.02Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:57.35Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:57.35Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:57.35Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:58:57.35Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:59:14.29Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:59:14.33Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:59:14.33Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:59:14.33Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:59:31.26Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:59:31.30Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:59:31.30Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:59:31.30Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:59:42.64Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:59:42.66Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:59:42.79Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:59:42.79Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:59:42.94Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:59:42.94Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:59:48.24Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:59:48.28Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:59:48.28Z 'I|PSnd:'
'2017-10-02T23:59:48.28Z 'I|PSnd:'
```

I am not getting anything after the PSnd and the second column is empty,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution without any for loops.

Basically firs search for lines with "snd".  Then check the next row for "sD".  Return the matched lines & tokens from the regexp of the lines that match.

```
fID = fopen('log1.txt');
C = textscan(fID,'%s','delimiter','\n');
fclose(fID);
C = C{1};
%Find all lines with snd
initMatchIdx = ~cellfun(@isempty,regexp(C,'^[0-9,-:T]*Z.*PSnd.*snd'));
%Check the lines 1 row down ... 
checkIdx = [false; initMatchIdx(1:end-1)];
%If it matches return the entire line and the tokens..
[temp, matchedLines] = regexp(C(checkIdx),'(?<date>^[0-9,-:T]*)Z.*PSnd.*sD\[(?<otherVal>\w*)\].*' ,'tokens','match');
%Do some reshaping and un-celling.
matchedLines = [matchedLines{:}]';
temp = [temp{:}];
temp = reshape([temp{:}],2,[])';
%Convert to Date
outTime  = datetime(temp(:,1),'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SS');
otherVal = temp(:,2);
```

The output looks like this:

```
>> outTime
outTime = 
   02-Oct-2017 15:29:47
   02-Oct-2017 15:29:47
   02-Oct-2017 15:29:47
   02-Oct-2017 15:29:47

>> otherVal    
otherVal = 
    '3D'
    'B0'
    '3D'
    '3D'

>> matchedLines
matchedLines = 
'2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'I|PSnd: 233|sD[3D]m:0x656...'
'2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'I|PSnd: 233|sD[B0]m:0x390...'
'2017-10-02T15:29:47.22Z 'I|PSnd: 233|sD[3D]m:0x41a...'
'2017-10-02T15:29:47.24Z 'I|PSnd: 233|sD[3D]m:0x51c...'
```

Comment: thank you very much, i worked perfectly ,i saw my mistakes and thanks for the response .. but i will still like to ask some other things

Is it possible to create this into like a function where i can call and it will get all the result i need into a folder either as txt or log, because i have multiple files. maybe i  will just change the search term and the file name.

Comment: also, the timing, last time, i need to extaract only the time out, like only the hour, but i couldn't do that and i have to extract them using excel which took a lotof time. I tried timing seperation as you can see in the code i posted, but am having having the hour, minute and secound seperately in different column. I used nearly all function possible. Please is this possible as well.

Comment: lastly, why can't i use the queryline as i used before.

Comment: You could make it a function if you want for use on multiple files.  Just make the filename an input to the function.   You could use make part of the regexp "querline" an input as well ... but since you are dependent on 2 separate lines it was easier for me to code it this way.

Comment: Also the time I returned in outTime is of the class `datetime` which contiains the entire date time group.  You can use the `datevec` function to extract out any piece of it you want  Ex. ` [Y,M,D,H,MN,S] = datevec(outTime )`

Comment: ohkay, thanks alot, i will do that ASAP and  get back to you on my results. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach:

- read the file as you did
- use a combination of `cellfun` and `strfind` to find the rows with `snd`
- do the same for `sD`

the two above will give the logical indices of the rows containing the two marks.

- create a matrix of logical values by pairing the two set of indices this way: all the idx but the last one of the first set, all the idx but the first of the second and
- add `1`
- look for the rows of the matrix with two `1`

Now you have the rows you are looking for.

In a loop:

- split the `i-th` row with respect to a blank: the first token is the date
- your format for the conversion seems incorrect, you should remove the last `S` at the end and add a `Z` (see below)
- strore the date in a `cellarray`
- use `strfind` to find the starting point of `[` in the row
- do the same for `]`
- the value (e. g. 3D) you are looking for is in between
- store the value in a `cellarray`

Now you have the dates, the values and the whole rows in three `cellarray`

Notice, additional check may be needed for inout files with different set of rows.

A possible implementation could be:

```
fID = fopen('log1.txt');
C = textscan(fID,'%s','delimiter','\n');
fclose(fID)

x=C{1};
% Find the row with "snd"
idx_1=~cellfun('isempty',(strfind(x,'snd')))
% Find the row with "sD"
idx_2=~cellfun('isempty',(strfind(x,'sD[')))
% Join the two indeces, shifting the second one of 1
% find the row of the matrix with 2 "1"
k=find(all([idx_1(1:end-1) idx_2(2:end)],2))+1
x{k}
% Loop over the identified rows
for i=1:length(k)
   % Split the row wrt ' ', the first elemetn is the date
   a=strsplit(x{i},' ')
   % Convert the date
   the_date{i}=datetime(a{1},'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SS''Z''')
   % look for the position of the "["
   start_idx=strfind(x{k(i)},'[')
   % look for the position of the "]"
   end_idx=strfind(x{k(i)},']')
   % Extract the value between the "[]"
   val{i}=x{k(i)}(start_idx+1:end_idx-1)
end
```

With respect to your inout file:

**Selected rows**

```
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'I|PSnd: 233|sD[3D]m:0x6564 e:0'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.18Z 'I|PSnd: 233|sD[B0]m:0x3901 e:0'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.22Z 'I|PSnd: 233|sD[3D]m:0x41a1 e:0'
2017-10-02T15:29:47.24Z 'I|PSnd: 233|sD[3D]m:0x51c8 e:0'
```

**Idx of the selected rows:**

```
 2
11
23
36
```

**Corresponding dates**

the_date =

```
  Columns 1 through 2

    [02-Oct-2017 15:29:47]    [02-Oct-2017 15:29:47]

  Columns 3 through 4

    [02-Oct-2017 15:29:47]    [02-Oct-2017 15:29:47]
```

**The corresponding values:**

```
val = 

    '3D'    'B0'    '3D'    '3D
```

Comment: Thanks alot, am just seeing this now, i will check it right away and get back to you ASAP.... regards

Comment: Hello, first the file am treating is a large text file, like 2 millions set of lines, and i need to extract them all in an array,  and the variable the_date is changing per loop and its really fulling the command prompt and its taking so long. Also how can i get the selected row as you stated. How can i combine both only the time and the Val in a single array.